# How to disable cross partitioning in query in Golang Mongo API for Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using the official mongo Golang SDK (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) to connect to Cosmos DB. I am looking for a way to disable the cross partition query. The other SDKs supported by Cosmos DB have this option.

Thanks
Guru

Comment: are you using this driver ? https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver

Comment: Yes. I use the same driver

Answer (score 0):

The only way to work with the MongoDB API of Cosmos DB is with a MongoDB-specific SDK, just like the one you're using for Go. And MongoDB-specific SDKs know nothing about Cosmos DB - they are designed specifically to work with MongoDB. This is why there is no obvious settings for performing/not-performing cross-partition queries. Only the Cosmos DB native SDKs will know anything about Cosmos DB specifics.

To target a particular partition in your container, using a MongoDB-specific driver, you would need to specify your container's partition key in your query (though MongoDB calls such a key a *shard* key).

You haven't provided any sample data, but... assuming you had a collection of companies and divisions, and `"company"` was your shard key, you could have a query that looks something like this:

```js
db.divisions.find( { division: 'marketing', company: 'ABC Corp' })
```

Since the shard key is specified, this avoids a cross-partition query.